# Is there a default template for dumping data from a view

Tags: django, view

I have complex models and would like to just 'dump' some querysets to see exactly what they contain from view code.

I tried the generic list_detail (from urls.py) - but it appears to require writing a template.

Is there a way to dump data from a view (like how json is saved) that will work with anything passed?

Comment: Writing a template is pretty much trivial.  What's the problem?

Answer (score 3):

You could serialize the queryset to XML and then return that in the response.  Something like:

```
from django.core import serializers

def view(request):
    xml = serializers.serialize('xml', FooModel.objects.all())
    response = HttpResponse(xml, mimetype='application/xml')
    return response
```

Comment: Thanks ars for the direction.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the built-in [databrowse](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/databrowse/) app?